# automatically partition audio files into small parts

Tags: audio, scripting

I am looking for a way to automatically extract parts from audio files. Something like Imagemagick for audio files.

I only need to extract random parts of a fixed length from a large set of complete ogg-vorbis files. I easily know how to automatically interpret the output from a programm, so I would be able to write a small script if I had programs to do the following:

1. Get the length of the file
2. Extract parts of the given an offset in seconds and a length

Is there any program, which allows me to do this under linux? The files I am using are ogg vorbis files.

If there is a python library, which is able to do this, it would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (Sound eXchange) to do both.